Where does the argument included below to "Prove the fundamental group of a Topological Group is abelian" fail for non-group topological spaces?
I came across this proof by Jason D. to show that for a topological group $G$, the fundamental group $\pi_1(G, e)$ is abelian. The argument is roughly as follows:

Consider two paths $c : [0, 1] \rightarrow G, \; s \mapsto c(s) \in G$ and $d : [0, 1] \rightarrow G, \; t \mapsto d(t) \in G$ starting and ending at $e \in G$. The goal is to show that $cd$ is homotopic to $dc$ (where $cd$ refers to the concatenation where we do $c$, then $d$).


Draw out the 2D plane spanned by perpendicular $s$, $t$ axes and consider the square $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ with $(s,t) = (0,0)$ being the bottom-left corner of the square and $(s,t)= (0, 1)$ being the top-left corner. Then we can interpret a point $(s, t) \in [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ as $c(s) * d(t)$ where $*$ denotes group multiplication.


Then, the path $cd$ corresponds to traversing horizontally along the bottom-edge of the square, following by traversing vertically up the right-edge. The path $dc$ corresponds to traversing vertically the left-edge and then horizontally the top-edge of the square.


Then, to find a homotopy between the two paths is the same as deforming one of these curves into the other while making sure we start at the bottom-left and end at the top-right, which we can do pretty easily.

This make sense to me, but I'm not sure how to properly show that this argument fails for a space with a hole(s) like, say, $S^1 \vee S^1$. Intuitively I feel like it'd be because when trying to continuously from, say, $cd$ to $dc$ we'd hit a snag because each point in $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ corresponds to the group multiplication $c(s) * d(t)$ which just gives us another point in $G$ and so in a space with a hole, there should be a corresponding "jump" or "discontinuity" in the mapping between the square and $G$. How would I argue for this rigorously?
Thank you!

It it not a priori clear that there exist spaces with non-abelian fundamental group.
The idea of the above proof is that we can "realize" $c * d$ by travelling from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$ via $c$ and then from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$ via $d$, whereas $d * c$ is realized by travelling from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ via $d$ and then from $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$ via $c$. Group multplication allows us to "fill" the square, which shows that $c * d$ and $d * c$ are path homotopic.
This way of filling is impossible without a group multiplication, but perhaps there is another method?
The only way to see that it is impossible in general is to give an example of a space with non-abelian fundamental group.
The space $S^1 \vee S^1$ is such an example.

To give you a very short literal answer to your question of where the argument fails, it fails here:

... we can interpret a point $(s,t) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$ as $c(s) * d(t)$ where $*$ denotes group multiplication...

Well, we cannot do that when there is no group multiplication.
